# Batch file only run once, FOR loop at fault

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I'm looking for a batch that look into folders that begins with "@" and then inside those folders have a subfolder named "Keys" copy a file.bikey to a static folder name "keys".

The for /d loop that I use apparently stops working due to a cd/goto commands inside.

```
Main
│   key-collector.bat
│
├───@folder_a
│   └───keys
│           a.txt
│
├───@folder_b
│   └───keys
│           b.txt
│
├───@folder_c
│   └───keys
│           c.txt
└───keys
    └───(Destination)
```

*Current code:*

```
@echo off
:start
set modsPath="C:\Exemple"
set keysPath="%modsPath%\keys"
for /d %%i in (@*) do (
    echo %%i
    copy /y %cd%\%%i\keys\*.txt %keysPath%
    ::cd %cd%\%%i\keys
    ::copy *.txt %keysPath%
    )
PAUSE>nul
exit
```

Comment: do not use an invalid label inside a code block. change `::` to `rem`. Then on the `cd` command, why even cd? just copy the files from full path or `pushd path` and `popd` after the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

1. set the path with double quotes including the variable name i.e `set "var=value"`
2. Do not use invalid labels `::` inside a code block, instead use `rem`
3. add double quotes to your paths for instance: `copy /y "%cd%\%%i\keys\*.txt" "%keysPath%"`
4. use `%%~fi` for the full path instead of `cd`

```
@echo off
:start
set "modsPath=C:\Example"
set "keysPath=%modsPath%\keys"
for /d %%i in (@*) do (
    echo %%~fi
    copy /y "%%~fi\keys\*.txt" "%keysPath%"
    rem comments like this
    )
pause>nul
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to understand the %%~fi, it returns:
%~fi (from echo) and 
"Path not found"

Comment: Did you copy the code as is? please double check. `%%~f` is a valid expansion for a variable. see `for /?` from `cmd`

Comment: I mixed up my actual batch with my copy for testing, it works well, I really do appreciate your help. thank you